# Simultaneous Autonomous Exploration and Mapping in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, navigation, exploration, frontier-exploration, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Gazebo, I place a [husky robot](https://github.com/husky/husky_description) in a completely unknown environment (currently the willowgarage map). My basic objective is to make the husky autonomously navigate itself through the entire world with the sole aim of mapping the entire area.
Basically, if anyone could tell me how to combine an exploration algorithm such as [frontier_exploration](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration) with gmapping, I would greatly appreciate it. Most tutorials out there use teleoperation, which really defeats the purpose I'm trying to achieve.

Thank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192160/simultaneous-autonomous-exploration-and-mapping-in-gazebo/) by [Ashwin27](https://answers.ros.org/users/19896/ashwin27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 34 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nikhil16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26369/nikhil16/) on 2016-03-22**:
Hi!

Did you manage to do it?

**Comment by [Ashwin27](https://answers.ros.org/users/19896/ashwin27/) on 2016-03-22**:
Hello Nikhil,
I moved forward with the Nav2d package by Sebastien mentioned in the answer below. I highly recommend it, it's a great place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The core idea is usually, that you have a complete goal navigation running on your robot and have your exploration module generate the targets depending on your current map and robot position. So a first step would be to check that mapping and navigation are working simultaneously.

I once used the exploration package from http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d within Gazebo and the willowgarage map, so this could be an option as well.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ashwin27](https://answers.ros.org/users/19896/ashwin27/) on 2014-09-08**:
Thanks, Sebastian! I'll give it a try.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-08**:
Hi @Sebastian Kasperski, can nav2d exploration package be used for a single robot autonomous exploration of an indoor workplace out of the box? - i have working navigation and mapping packages running. thanks

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-11**:
Hi @sobot, exploration should work out of the box if you use the mapping and navigation from the nav2d package. (see [Tutorial3](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d/Tutorials/MultiMapper#Autonomous_Exploration))

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-11**:
thanks a bunch @Sebastian Kasperski , i will give it a try for sure. just a little question, do i also have to add the GetFirstMap action which is mentioned in the tutorial, like the other two GetMap & Explore in the launch file? my ultimate goal is to test an autonomous navigation solution.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-11**:
@sobot: The GetFirstMap action only drives the robot forward a bit and makes it turn 360° to build an initial map. This is because the exploration cannot work on an empty map. The client-nodes are only simple shortcuts to call these actions from the command line.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-11**:
@Sebastian Kasperski Correct, i understand the reason for of it. was just wondering about the launch file config to do "Autonomous" exploration on robot. GetFirstMap is not in the sample launch files, do i have to add it just like GetMap? which service number calls it? so much want it to work! thnx.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-11**:
@sobot: But it is there: [tutorial3.launch](https://github.com/skasperski/navigation_2d/blob/master/nav2d_tutorials/launch/tutorial3.launch#L30). It is called [get_map_client](https://github.com/skasperski/navigation_2d/blob/master/nav2d_navigator/src/get_map_client.cpp).

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-11**:
Ok, got me, the naming might be a little inconsistent...

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-11**:
Thank you for the elaboration @Sebastian Kasperski, i will try the package soon.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-13**:
Hi again @Sebastian Kasperski , i installed and tried nav2d, ran into a couple of problems. i posted a question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/209177/nav2d-autonomouse-exploration/) . i'd appreciate it if you take a look. more info is available if needed. Thanks!